# Find the common ratio given $n$ via sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $S_n$ be the sum of the first $n$ elements of the geometric sequence. We know that
$$\log_3\left(\frac{S_n}{2}+1\right)=n$$
Given this, determine the common ratio $r$.

---

*My attempt*

We've got
$$\log_3\left(\frac{S_n}{2}+1\right)=n$$
We can remove the logarithm by raising both sides to $3$.
$$\frac{S_n}{2}+1=3^n$$
Let's subtract $1$ from both sides
$$\frac{S_n}{2}=3^n-1$$
Now, let's multiply everything by $2$
$$S_n=2 \cdot 3^n-2$$
Now, let's rewrite $S_n$
$$a_1\left(\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\right)=2\cdot3^n-2$$
I can continue, but it doesn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: $S_n-S_{n-1}=a_n$ for $n>1$. Instead of rewriting $S_n$ (last step), try to find $a_n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_1=2(3^1-1) $ and $S_2=2(3^2-1)$

$\Rightarrow a_1=4 \ and \ a_2=S_2-S_1= 16-4=12 \Rightarrow r=\frac{a_2}{a_1}=3$

Answer (score 0):

The formula is valid for **any** $n\ge 1$. Plugging in $n=1$ yields $a_1=4$. For $n=2$, you get $r=3$. If you use these values, $$4\left(\frac{1-3^n}{1-3}\right)=4\frac{3^n-1}{2}=2\cdot3^n-2$$
This verifies your last identity.